# multiply columns of a table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a table with a column which contains areas of soil types and a column with the productivities of the different soil types (ton/ha). I would like to multiply these columns to have the total productivity (in ton) but I cannot figure out how to do this. Can someone help?

Comment: you mean something different than `select soil_type * productivity`?

Comment: And please post the definition of the table (ideally as `create table`) some sample data (ideally as `insert into`) and the expected output based on that sample data.